# No result when wrapping working `forecast()` statement in `tryCatch()`

Tags: r, try-catch, forecasting

I have a large number of time series for which I would like to generate forecasts. In order to automatically generate the best forecast I would like to apply a number of models such as auto.arima, ets, (s)naive, neural network etc. Unfortunately, when it loops through the time series some models fail, which stop the execution of the R script. In order to make this more robust I started using `tryCatch()`; my main objective with this is that I would the script to continue not necessary catching the errors. When executing the code, the `forecast()` within the `tryCatch()` fails to produce a proper forecast.

Please find below a reproducable example of the error that I am encounter.

Historical timeseries:

```
ts <- structure(c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 9, 10, 10, 16, 7, 13, 0, 9, 1, 11, 2, 11, 3, 
11, 4, 1, 20, 13, 13, 13, 9, 14, 16, 16, 18, 17, 20, 18, 19, 
16, 16, 16, 15, 14, 27, 24, 35, 8, 18, 21, 20, 19, 22, 18, 21, 
19, 24, 33, 23, 18, 26, 18, 17, 19, 19, 22, 19, 24, 29, 29, 18
), .Tsp = c(2025.25, 2032.16666666667, 12), class = "ts")
```

The following line of code produces a proper forecast:

```
fcast_arima <- forecast(auto.arima(ts),h=4)
fcast_arima
         Point Forecast    Lo 80    Hi 80    Lo 95    Hi 95
Apr 2032       24.69032 18.57094 30.80971 15.33153 34.04911
May 2032       25.00539 18.84018 31.17061 15.57651 34.43428
Jun 2032       25.32046 19.10975 31.53118 15.82200 34.81893
Jul 2032       25.63554 19.37966 31.89141 16.06800 35.20307
```

When I wrap the same code into a `tryCatch` line it fails to produce a forecast, see example below:

```
fcast_arima <- tryCatch({ fcast_arima <- forecast(auto.arima(ts),h=4)}, warning = function(warningcondition) {message(warningcondition)}, error = function(errorcondition) {message(errorcondition)}, finally={})
p-value smaller than printed p-value
fcast_arima
NULL
```

Can anybody explain why the code that is working fine without the `tryCatch()` is not working within a `tryCatch()`?

Comment: Why don't you simply use `try(forecast(auto.arima(ts),h=4))`?

Comment: There are two problems with your approach: 1. Your warning handler returns `NULL`. Maybe `demo(error.catching)` can help you with this. 2. I don't understand the warning from forecast. It doesn't make sense.

Comment: The warning is from `auto.arima(ts)` but only when run inside a `tryCatch` expression with a warning handler. `tryCatch(auto.arima(ts),warning=function(w){cat("Warning: ");message(w)})`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm thinking that something is suppressing warnings by setting `options(warn=-1)`, and generating a warning. I can simulate the behaviour you are seeing here.

Create a function that generates a warning and returns 99 but with the warning suppressed by options:

```
> foo=function(){o=options()$warn; options(warn=-1);warning("Yikes!");options(warn=o);return(99)}
```

That seems to run nicely:

```
> foo()
[1] 99
```

And I can run it in a simple `tryCatch`:

```
> tryCatch(foo())
[1] 99
```

But the warning gets trapped if I add a `warning` clause:

```
> tryCatch(foo(),warning=function(w){message(w)})
Yikes!>
```

Although it still seems to run without warnings:

```
> foo()
[1] 99
```

I'm not sure what the solution is... Sorry... Perhaps getting whoever wrote the code that tries to suppress the warning to rewrite it to use `suppressWarnings` instead:

```
> foo=function(){suppressWarnings({warning("Yikes!")}) ; return(99)}
> foo()
[1] 99
> tryCatch(foo(),warning=function(w){message(w)})
[1] 99
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, this clarifies what is happening.

Comment: FYI: The author of the `forecast` package added this to his GitHub issue list. More info via https://github.com/robjhyndman/forecast/issues/55